# iOS NSPredicate for all items in core data based on a condition

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Hi I have 2 entities in Core Data that matter for this example:

- Filter
- Item

Of course, certain **Items** belong to a **Filter**.
Now a **Filter** has an attribute **withPictureOnly** that indicates that the items in the filter should have a picture.

When Im parsing the data and saving I am saving every Item even if it doesn't have a picture not considering the filter flag **withPictureOnly**, but when I'm fetching the data from Core Data, **I'd like to fetch from all Filters, but if a filter has the attribute withPictureOnly, then fetch only the Items that have pictures**

And I have been thinking about it a lot and the only option I can think of is to fetch the data separately into two arrays and then merge the arrays. But that seem not to be really efficient.

Is there a way I could do this right with just one NSPredicate and one fetch?

Thanks

Comment: Please can you show the full data model for these two entities.  What are you fetching - Items or Filters?  And how are pictures modelled - another entity, related to Items, or as an attribute?